# how does the recursion work on sicp lecture 3b if you feed it multiple sum?

Tags: scheme

I'm viewing the lesson here on calculating the deriviative of an algebraic expression:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X21cKVtGvYk

I sort of understand how it's working but how does it find the deriviative of an expression like  ax^3 + bx^2 + cx, since it has 3 subparts to work out?

```
(define (deriv exp var)
    (cond
        ((CONST? exp var) 0)
        ((SAME-VAR? exp var) 1)
        ((SUM? exp)
            (make-sum
                (deriv (A1 exp) var)
                (deriv (A2 exp) var)))
        ((PRODUCT? exp)
            (make-sum
                (make-product
                    (M1 exp)
                    (deriv (M2 exp) var))
                (make-product
                    (deriv (M1 exp) var)
                    (M2 exp))))
        ; ... more rules
        )
    )
;# END BOARD



;# BOARD 0:14:50
(define (CONST? exp var)
    ; An expressin is constant if:
    ; - I cannot break it up into more primitive pieces
    ; - It's not var
    (AND
        (ATOM? exp)
        (NOT (EQ? exp var)))
    )

(define (SAME-VAR? exp var)
    (AND
        (ATOM? exp)
        (EQ? exp var))
    )
;# END BOARD



;# BOARD 0:17:35
(define (SUM? exp)
    ; An expression is a sum if its first element equals '+
    (AND
        (NOT (ATOM? exp))
        (EQ (CAR exp) '+)) ; Notice the quotation.
    )

(define (make-sum a1 a2)
    (LIST '+ a1 a2))

(define a1 cadr)
;# END BOARD
```

Comment: Unless you've done the exercises you split it up like this: `'(+ (* a (* x x x)) (+ (* b (* x x)) (* c x)))`.

Comment: I learned the basic rules of differentiation and integration.  The fact is we're using list structure to break the statement '(+ (* a (* x x )) (+ (* b (* x )) c ))) into two - 'cadr' and 'caddr'. That was the key to understanding the code. I was confused on how the 'c' was being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

ax^3 + bx^2 + cx will be represented like (ax^3 + bx^2) + cx. so it's two sums of two elements.